# How to get the full HTTP request URL using Apache httpd API (request_rec)?

Tags: c++, apache

I need to create a code in CPP that get the full HTTP request URL from `request_rec` (http://ci.apache.org/projects/httpd/trunk/doxygen/structrequest__rec.html)

(In my httpd I do not manipulate URL it so I suppose it is not changed)

For example, if a user is accesses to `http:/server1/application1/page1` I will be able to get it on the server side.

I have tried to use `the_request` but it do not print the server name (http://ci.apache.org/projects/httpd/trunk/doxygen/structrequest__rec.html#a5c79d3735ea2005964f2d4cb83f5b461)

**Added**

The example of the function I need in Java http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to manage it using
`const char* ap_get_server_name (request_rec* r)`

http://ci.apache.org/projects/httpd/trunk/doxygen/group__APACHE__CORE__HTTPD.html#ga730a2e07b3de80cf25bc78546bffab34