# How to get the full HTTP request URL using Apache httpd API and request_rec?

Tags: c, apache

I am writing an Apache module in C and I'm looking to apply a regular expression across the entire HTTP URL for the current request (via `request_rec`). I cannot find any member of `request_rec` that contains this information. I've tried

- `the_request`
- `unparsed_uri`
- `uri`
- `ap_get_server_name(r)`
- `path_info`
- `parsed_uri.path`

... to name a few.

How can I get the entire URL as a single `char *`?

I understand this question is similar to the one linked below, but this is for the C language (they're using C++) and their solution (I tried anyways) has not worked for me.

[How to get the full HTTP request URL using Apache httpd API (request_rec)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985057/how-to-get-the-full-http-request-url-using-apache-httpd-api-request-rec)

Comment: You are making wrong assumptions. An HTTP request consists of multiple headers, none of which contain the full URI. None of the internal functions need the full URI. If you need that, you need to construct those from the Host header (`ap_get_server_name`), the path, the scheme, etc? So what exactly did you try? I don't see your code.

Comment: @Cheatah Alright, that's fine. I can build it myself: I just didn't want to if the information could be found elsewhere in the API already constructed. All I needed was confirmation that this information did/did-not exist. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find this information already available in the httpd API (as Cheatah suggested), so I used the following function to build the information myself.

DISCLAIMER: When I was testing this against the url `sub.localhost/a/b/c?query=param` the port values under `request_rec` were unpopulated, so I'm not attempting at this time to handle different ports as it's not important for my use-case.

```
const char *buildUrl(request_rec *r)
{
    char *url = apr_pcalloc(r->pool, urlMaxLength);

    // <scheme>://<host><:port(IFF!=80)><unparsed-uri>
    snprintf(url, urlMaxLength, "%s://%s%s%s",
        ap_http_scheme(r),
        r->hostname,
        "", // could not get port # from request_rec... let's just assume that won't be needed...
        r->unparsed_uri
    );

    return url;
}
```

Comment: The result is incorrect if use `mod_rewrite` and `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Interesting. I am not using those modules, so this will still work for me. 

Regardless, for the benefit of those who may be, can you explain why that goes wrong?

Comment: By example `RewriteRule ^en/$ /en.html [L]` the `r->uri` and `r->unparsed_uri` is `/en.html` but the real request is `/en/`, there is no variable that shows the actual http request made by the browser. in PHP the real uri is obtained from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, but `request_rec` does not have this parsed value from plain request first line (`r->the_request`).

Answer (score 0):

```c
static int on_request(request_rec *r) {

  // Substraction for request uri (r->uri is broken when use mod_rewrite)
  char *request_uri = calloc(strlen(r->the_request), 1);
  long unsigned int i;
  for(i = strlen(r->method) + 1; i <= (strlen(r->the_request) - strlen(r->protocol) - 1); i++) {
      request_uri[i - strlen(r->method) - 1] = r->the_request[i];
  }

  // Use it

  free(request_uri);

  // ...
```

For http://example.com/abc/def.html?ghi=jkl the `request_uri` is `/abc/def.html?ghi=jkl`.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is intended to work, but I can tell you the result I get running this code is "(null)".

Comment: Get real request uri from main http request, by example: `GET /foo/bar?a=b HTTP/1.1`, but with a substring from end of method at begin protocol version: The quequest uri.